# Use an image from the web for WPF Image controller

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an image ui element and i need it to show a jpg image from the web.

I tried using:

`Bitmap.FromStream(new WebClient().OpenRead(url));`

But it didn't work..
I'd love to get a proper solution.

Comment: How did it `not work`?

Comment: Maybe because `WPF` does not use `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

Comment: Bitmap inherits from Image, doesn't it what Image controller needs to get?

Comment: We need a little more detail than just "it didn't work".  That doesn't really help anyone looking at the question.

Comment: It simply didn't show the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` instead of a `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`

You can apply an `ImageSource` many ways

Example using Url string

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication13
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ImageUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2836444.png";
        }

        private string _imageUrl;
        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get { return _imageUrl; }
            set { _imageUrl = value; INotifyPropertyChanged("ImageUrl"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void INotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="428" Width="738" Name="UI" >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:
[image]